# Can I make an web application by using Salesforce?

Tags: force.com

I am SalesForce beginner and trying to make an web application to manage projects.

I don't know where to start, what materials to make it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest starting with Trailhead as it contains probably all basic things you need to know about Salesforce. You can also answer and practice coding with it as it will be connected to your developer account.

https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead

You can also start making an app here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Quick_Tutorial_1:_Build_a_Cloud_App_in_5_Minutes

Comment: Thanks, I will try the Trailhead course. But before my question was here, I have read many instruction at Force.com. Then I downloaded the Eclipse and started reading about Apec... so can you help me to understand the way I am. I lost my way to learn SalesForce. Actually, I want to make an Web App like Trello, it's an Project Management website, It's can manage project, deadline, task....and of course, my boss love to make the CRM, app from Salesforce

Comment: Which part are you right now? I started learning apex code with sublime text 3 + mavensmate but I transfered to eclipse + force.com IDE because all my friends use it.

Comment: I am in beginner part!

Comment: hello.
Basically, I don't know does it like Zend or Symfony or any Framework to help making the site like Trello.com. I am a Junior English Reading – Can you help me!

Answer (score 0):

Apart from learning Apex and Visualforce you can go through [this link](http://appirio.com/category/tech-blog/2015/01/strategies-building-customer-facing-salesforce-apps/). It is a very good article on Building Customer Facing Salesforce Apps. Regarding the project management app here is a [source code](http://developer.force.com/codeshare/projectpage?id=a06300000030vyrAAA) available on how to create Gantt chart  in Salesforce using Apex and VisualForce from Force.com Code Share. I hope this will be a good starting point for you.